# ADT Prompt to reinstal support library

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

So every time I try to add support library to a project I'm prompted to reinstall support library v8. Its not a major issue because it will get added after install its just an annoying issue. I've tried with both eclipse 3.6 and 3.7. I've also tried to remove support library. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I reported this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27435) a month ago. If you have a significantly different environment than the ones listed there, you might want to add your details.

Comment: That's very useful to know. I had been trying to change an app to make use of a LocalBroadcastManager and thought that my Eclipse/SDK installation must have become corrupted. My mind is now at ease.

Comment: Reported the same issue, was hoping someone had a workaround or could shed some new light on the issue.

Comment: @Warpzit: The workaround is not to use the menu choice. Unless you are seeking `GridLayout`, just copy the requisite JAR into your project's `libs/` directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess thats the best we can do. Did this problem come with the new version of support library or when? It might be a fingerprint issue then.

Comment: @Warpzit: I ran into it when I upgraded to the R17 tools.